errors not showing up on sentry dashboard (vite react tsx project)
I have set up sentry for my project as per the sentry react docs, but the errors were not showing up in the sentry dashboard.
when i use debug: true in sentry init the logs appear in my consol.
my sentry  setup in main.tsx
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";

 Sentry.init({
   dsn: "https://***",
   integrations: [
     Sentry.browserTracingIntegration(),
     Sentry.replayIntegration(),
   ],
   // Tracing
   tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
   replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
   replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
   // debug: true,
 });

I also wrapped ErrorBoundary over my app component
<Sentry.ErrorBoundary fallback={<p>An error has occurred</p>}>
<App />
</Sentry.ErrorBoundary>

no error were displayed in my sentry error dashboard.
so I set the debug mode to true in sentry init in order to check for the messages locally. when i did that i sentry properly logged the errors in my consol. these are the logs that i expect to appear on my sentry dashboard. Can some one tell me what should i do to make it work?
